# A priest grants absolution to a man who turns out to be an android

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

This was a science fiction short-story that I read circa 1950-1960s (and published 1950s-1960s).

A Catholic priest has a long acquaintance with a chess-playing friend who regularly attends mass and receives holy communion. He asks the priest for absolution as he is dying and is revealed to be an android.

Comment: I'm away from my library, but this sounds like an Anthony Boucher story - at least it's in his wheelhouse.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

["Last Rites"](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?56981), a short story by [Charles Beaumont](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Charles_Beaumont), first published in [*If*, October 1955](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?58826+c), available at the [Internet Archive](https://archive.org/details/1955-10_IF/page/n89/mode/1up). There is no mention of chess, and the sacrament the android wants the priest to administer is [Extreme Unction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anointing_of_the_Sick_in_the_Catholic_Church) (the anointing of the sick) rather than [Penance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sacrament_of_Penance) (Confession), but otherwise the story is much as you described it.

> There was a long pause, then he said, "Let me pose you a theoretical problem, Father. Something I've been thinking about lately."
>
> Father Courtney recalled the sentence, and how many times it had begun the evenings of talk—wonderful talk! These evenings, he realized, were part of his life now. An important part. For there was no one else, no one of Donovan's intelligence, with whom you could argue any subject under the sun—from Frescobaldi to baseball, from Colonization on Mars to the early French symbolists, to agrarian reforms, to wines, to theology.
>
> [. . .]
>
> "We have this man, Father," Donovan said, gazing at the ceiling. "He looks perfectly ordinary, you see, and it would occur to no one to doubt this; but he is not ordinary. Strictly speaking, he isn't even a man. For, though he lives, he isn't alive. You follow? He is a thing of wires and coils and magic, a creation of other men. He is a machine . . ."
>
> "George!" The priest shook his head. "We've gone through this before: it's foolish to waste time. I came here to help you, not to engage in a discussion of science fiction themes!"
>
> "But that's how you can help me," Donovan said.
>
> [. . .]
>
> The old man made a sharp noise. "But you can tell me this much," he said. "If our theoretical man were dying, and you knew that he was dying, would you give him Extreme Unction?"
>
> The priest shook his head. "It would be sacrilegious."
>
> "But why? You said yourself that he might have a soul, that God might have granted him this. Didn't you say that?"
>
> "I—"
>
> "Father, remember, he's a friend of yours. You know him well. You and he, this creature, have worked together, side by side, for years. You've taken a thousand walks together, shared the same interests, the same love of art and knowledge. For the sake of the thesis, Father. Do you understand?"
>
> "No," the priest said, feeling a chill freeze into him. "No, I don't."
>
> "Just answer this then. If your friend were suddenly to reveal himself to you as a machine, and he was dying, and wanted very much to go to Heaven—what would you do?"
>
> The priest picked up the wine glass and emptied it. He noticed that his hand was trembling. "Why—" he began, and stopped, and looked at the silent old man in the bed, studying the face, wearching for madness, for death.
>
> *"What would you do?"*
>
> An unsummoned image flashed through his mind. Donovan, kneeling at the altar for Communion, Sunday after Sunday; Donovan, with his mouth firmly shut, while the others yawned; Donovan, waiting to the last moment, then snatching the Host, quickly, dartingly, like a lizard grabbing a fly.
>
> Had he ever seen Donovan eat?
>
> Had he seen him take even one glass of wine, ever?
>
> Father Courtney shuddered slightly, brushing away the images. He felt unwell.

Comment: I believe you've got it!  Feel silly that I hadn't searched on 'last rites' which was a segment of my own recalled description of the story.  Thank you very much.  Have a good Sunday.  And a good Monday too, if you so chose.

Comment: I didn't remember the author or title either, but I remembered reading it in [*The First World of If*](http://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?39888) which I still have.

Comment: @TyCobb: It's a funny story. But if the android is as intelligent as he is purported to be, wouldn't he know that God does not care whether the priest gives any last rites or not? More important is to discuss in detail what best to do after he passes away.

Comment: I wonder how the android disposes of the commumion wafers that he's been taking every Sunday.

Comment: "wouldn't he know that God does not care whether the priest gives any last rites or not" well that's a question only someone unfamiliar with the theology behind last rites would ask.